# inline-block elements evenly spaced inside variable width container

Tags: css, html

I am trying to evenly space out inline-elements inside a 90% width container. I already looked for a solution and tried different things with zero success.

The most promising idea was the text-align: justify with and 100% width child

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="stage">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img src="generic_source" height="200px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <img src="generic_source" height="200px"/>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#stage {
   width: 90%;
   margin: 50px auto;
   text-align: justify;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
#stage::after {
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
   content:'';
}
.thumb {
   height: 200px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 10px;
   width: 300px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 2px;
}
```

Everything looks great except the space left on the right. Zooming in and out makes it more or less obvious, but obvious nonetheless

I have 100+ thumbs that i would like to see symmetrically arranged

Thank you

EDIT:
Here you can see the example. Notice the space left to the right side border when scaling the page

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem. Currently the only problem description you have is "Everything looks great except the space left on the right" which is absolutely not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way to do it in css is by using flexbox. You'll need to change #stage selector:

```
#stage{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

if you can't use it (need to support older browsers) you can try a js solution like [freewall](http://kombai.github.io/freewall/)